# Can you change 10B into 10,000,000,000 in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with monetary values that are recorded with the following format

```
84.6M
4.64B
1.814M
14K
12.3B
etc
```

*Edit* The tens are just an example all the numbers are financial data and vary wildly

Is there a way to have excel remove the B and multiply the leftover number by 1,000,000,000?
Same thing need for the million and thousand markers

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple search and replace? "10B" with "10000000000", the format the cells to show commas.

Comment: I just gave these numbers as an example. All numbers are wildly different

Comment: It's usually helpful for sample data to be representative of actual data. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Consider replaceing K, M and B with the appropriate number of zeroes or multiplying the number preceing the letter with the appropriate mutiplier (`*1,000`, `*1,000,000` or `*1,000,000,000` as the case may be)

Comment: Case one doesn't work with my data, and the second one is not time efficient. Also why is everyone answering in the comment section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little easier to expand:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1),{"K","M","B"},0)*3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do a series of nested if statements

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="B",
        LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*1000000000,
        IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="M",
            LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*1000000,
            IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="K",
                LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*1000,
                A1
            )
        )
    ),
    A1
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for